# Convexity condition for smooth submanifold-with-boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: convex-analysis, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

One can prove that a differentiable function $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is strictly convex if and only if for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$$f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)\leq f(x)\qquad\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R},$$
where equality occurs only at $x=a$. If this is the case, then the tangent line of $f$ through $(a,f(a))$ is the unique line through $(a,f(a))$ which has no intersection with the set $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y>f(x)\}. $ In a similar vein, is the following statement true?

> Let $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth, compact, connected,  $n$-dimensional submanifold-with-boundary. Then $M$ is a convex set if and only if for each $x\in \partial M$, the tangent space $(\partial M)_x$ has no intersection with $M\setminus\partial M$. If this is the case, then $(\partial M)_x$ is the unique $(n-1)$-dimensional hyperplane through $x$ which has no intersection with $M\setminus\partial M$.

Comment: By $M-\partial M$ do you mean the Minkowski sum or do you mean $M\setminus\partial M$?

Comment: @Zim I apologize for the ambiguity, I mean $M\setminus \partial M$, I'll edit the question to reflect this.